# Oracle Database Mobile Server for android

Tags: android, oracle, dms

What is the cause for this "oracle.opensync.ose.OSEException(-12039): Internal error has occured (see the cause) <- java.lang.NullPointerException" error in mobile sync android?

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same issue. You need to initiaize AndroidPlatformFactory with you activity context:

```
((AndroidPlatformFactory) PlatformFactory.getInstance()).setContext(<Your Activity>.this);
```